# Good Syntax Highlighter For Self-Hosted WordPress Blog

Tags: php, wordpress, syntax, syntax-highlighting

I am looking for a good automatic syntax highlighter for self-hosted WordPress blog (not wordpress.com blog). It would be great if the syntax highlighter automatically detects code parts and highlights them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Google Code Prettify is a fairly standard syntax highlighter, and there are multiple wordpress plugins that use it. Here's an example of one: http://www.deanlee.cn/wordpress/google-code-prettify-for-wordpress/

Comment: +1. I also wrote a tool to help escaping code for it, as the < bracket needs escaping: http://www.stum.de/2008/10/19/escaping-code-for-posting-on-the-website-and-removing-indent/

Answer (score 2):

I use [Syntax Highlighter Plus](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/syntaxhighlighter-plus/) for a while now and I'm kinda happy with it.

Answer (score 2):

Just for anyone else coming to this question after-the-fact (as I did), after much installation/removal of other plug-ins, I settled on [SyntaxHighlighter2](http://mohanjith.com/2009/03/syntaxhighlighter2.html) because it doesn't require me to go into HTML mode and enter `pre` tags directly and the syntax is manageable (`[code='js']...[/code]`). This is one of the many that uses the [SyntaxHighlighter 2.0](http://alexgorbatchev.com/wiki/SyntaxHighlighter) client-side highlighting script from Alex Gorbatchev (and so if you want server-side, it isn't for you).